# How to add Storage reference?

Tags: c#-4.0, xna

This should be pretty straightforward, but can't work this out for myself I'm afraid!

The following line of code triggers the error:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
```

> Error: The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

But as far as I can tell, I have added the reference: (Solution explorer -> right click References -> Add reference -> .NET tab -> scroll down to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage` -> select it -> click OK).

`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage` shows up when I expand "references" in the solution explorer.

What am I missing?

EDIT

Okay on second look this might be to do with how I'm adding the references. When I search in the object browser Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage doesn't show up (but when I search, for example, for audio, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio does show up). Is there anyway to check that when I click "OK" on the add reference pop-up that it is actually working?

Comment: Is this a phone project, by any chance?  I'm guessing this functionality isn't supported on whatever platform you're targeting.

Comment: No, it's a windows desktop project. How do I go about checking I'm not accidentally building a phone project?

Answer (score 2):

I see two likely possibilities.

1. You have a mismatch of XNA 4.0 and XNA 3.1 (or previous) references in your project.  If the Storage reference you added is from 3.1, you'll get this message.  You can try removing it, and then looking specifically for the 4.0 version during add.
2. The device you are building for may not support the Storage mechanism.  In particular, Windows Phone apparently uses a different storage mechanism (`System.IO.IsolatedStorage` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604992.aspx).

Hope one of these helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I've tried 1) - I removed the reference and checked that the version number was 4.0 when I re-added it, and I'm as sure as I can be that it is.

With 2, I'm using Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop, is there any way I can check that a) this is definitely the version I'm using, and b) that this version supports Storage

Comment: As long as you are building for Windows Desktop as your *target* (and not Windows Phone as the *target*), Storage should be available.  It doesn't depend on your version of Visual Studio.  Another possibility is that you may need to edit your .csproj file directly to make sure that the target framework is 4.0.

Comment: Okay - stupid question but how do I do that? When I build the game it runs as a Windows application so I'm assuming the target is Windows desktop. How do I go about editing the .csproj file? I can't find it in the file directory

Comment: From within Visual Studio, right-click the project name and choose "Open Folder in Windows Explorer."  The .csproj file should be there.

Comment: Thanks - found it. I'm afraid I still can't see what's wrong. The contents of the file are copied above in case it's useful

Comment: You might not have the right file still.  For a typical XNA project, you will have all your references listed in that file.  In other words, the contents will be quite large.

Comment: Btw - I'm somewhat unfamiliar with Visual Studio Express.  It may be that specifying references is handled differently for that environment.

Comment: Can't find this file anywhere I'm afraid

Comment: Okay on second look this might be to do with how I'm adding the references. When I search in the object browser Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage doesn't show up (but when I search, for example, for audio, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio does show up). Is there anyway to check that when I click "OK" on the add reference pop-up that it is actually working?

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked a long time ago, but if anyone else is still looking for an answer, here is how i fixed it.

If you installed the Microsoft.Xna.Framework references by using the installer from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914), then it installs in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly. I found all of the Xna libraries in *GAC_32* and Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage in *GAC_MSIL*.

You can also use the GAC to find libraries that aren't in Visual Studio's reference list. For .NET Framework versions before 4.0, the libraries are in **C:\Windows\assembly**, and the libraries for versions after 4.0 are in **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly**.

Answer (score 1):

**It's actually been removed from Monogame by Microsoft.**

Running: Windows 10, with integrated graphics card (Intel G45/G43), Visual Studio 19, Monogame 3.7.1

Project Structure: Solution > Game.Shared, Game.Android, Game.OpenGL (followed [this guide](https://manbeardgames.com/tutorials/multiplatform-game-development-with-monogame/#multiplatform-game-development-with-monogame) on creating a Cross-Platform project, method number 3).

<s>I changed the Target Framework in my OpenGL project from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.7.x (the newest version), and I was able to build and deploy the app to an Android device. Do this by clicking the project and selecting Properties.</s>

I simply commented out the line. App will successfully deploy to an Android device this way. The game will then deploy, *but I can't get any content to load.*

Have yet to see if I can deploy to an iOS device, I will update this post when I figure out if I can.

No nuGet's installed.

Comment: I will gladly send a .zip of my project if anyone wants the whole code.